# Javascript window eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that I can't seem to understand. I have a navbar and a hero section with svg images added separately. In javascript I created a window.addEventListener so on scroll certain styles changing, margin or postition:

```
let moon = document.querySelector(".moon") as HTMLElement | null;
let stars = document.getElementsByClassName("stars") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
let backMountains = document.querySelector(".backMountains") as HTMLElement | null;
let frontMountains = document.querySelector(".frontMountains") as HTMLElement | null;
let heroText = document.querySelector(".heroText") as HTMLElement | null;
let heroBtn = document.querySelector(".heroBtn") as HTMLElement | null;
let navBar = document.querySelector(".navBar") as HTMLElement | null;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let value = window.scrollY;

  for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].style.left = value * 0.25 + "px";
  }
  if (moon !== null) {
    moon.style.top = value * 1.05 + "px";
  }
  if (backMountains !== null) {
    backMountains.style.top = value * 0.5 + "px";
  }
  if (frontMountains !== null) {
    frontMountains.style.top = value * 0 + "px";
  }
  if (heroText !== null) {
    heroText.style.marginRight = value * 5 + "px";
    heroText.style.marginTop = value * 1.5 + "px";
  }
  if (heroBtn !== null) {
    heroBtn.style.marginTop = value * 1.5 + "px";
  }
  if (navBar !== null) {
    navBar.style.marginTop = value * 0.5 + "px";
  }
});
```

(stars are in a for loop because I had to make 3  to cover the area with smaller and bigger stars)

The tricky part is is that if I refresh the page only the stars moving nothing else...
If I change something in the code and save VS Code all of the event listener are working if I am not refreshing, if I do bumm.. only stars moving on scroll..

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Instead of `window` try `document.body`

Comment: Your core difficulty seems to be that browser-refresh produces something different than saving in VSCode -- which implies that you're using some kind of hot-reloading mechanism (like webpack-dev-server). Since the hot-reload situation works, it sounds like the problem is that you're expecting some state to persist across page views, which will not happen magically. You may need to store data on the server or using [web storage tech](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Comment: If you look at the documentation of the `window` object, `scroll` is not one of the events that exist for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#events

Comment: @KonradLinkowski The `window` object does not have a scroll event. However `document` and `document.body` both have the scroll event.

Comment: trigger the scroll code on page load.

Comment: We need to see more of both the CSS and the HTML markup to see what could be wrong there. What you show in your code should work. @slebetman the scroll event is part of the [Window-reflecting body element event handler set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#window-reflecting-body-element-event-handler-set), it does fire on `window` too.